# Review system with login / signup required

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm writing a review system for items in Ruby on Rails. I want the process to be as follow:

1. users to start entering their review/ratings

   when they hit submit, if they're not logged in, users are redirected to the signup or login page,

   they create and account or signup

   they're redirected to the post where they wrote a review, and the review is added.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some highlights

1. Use Authlogic

   - In your Review Controller, say something like before_filter :require_user_before_reviews
   - In require_user_before_reviews do something like

/app/controllers/reviews_controller.rb

```
  def require_user_before_reviews
    return true if logged_in?
    session[:review_params] = params[:review]
    session[:return_url] = new_review_path
    redirect_to login_path
  end
```

Then re-render the form on new_review_path with the session value after logged in.

There's some broad strokes in there, but that should work.

As a note: as a User, I'd want you to ask me to login before I do the review.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! But it's not working as is: the log mentions "Redirected to http://localhost:3000/login", "Filter chain halted as [:require_user_before_comments] rendered_or_redirected." and the login view is not displayed... can't find out how to solve this problem :( Any clue?

Comment: sounds like maybe require_user_before_comments is occurring in the application_controller? If not, try logging inside require_user_before_reviews to see when it's being called. It should only be called once.